# Analyzing firmware file with angr

Tags: firmware, fuzzing, angr, symbolic-execution

I want to use *angr* to analyze IoT firmware file. I have read the documentation of *angr*,however, I could not find solution to analyze firmware file. So how can *angr* generate CFG file of Firmware? or How I can analyze firmware file with *angr* as symbolic execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, `angr` does not do firmware file analysis: it is a binary (as in **binary executable**) analysis tools, and a firmware image is **not** an executable binary.

> So how can angr generate CFG file of Firmware?

As per my comment above, there is no such thing as the CFG of a firmware:
A CFG is the representation of the flow of control in an executable.

> How I can analyze firmware file with angr [with] symbolic execution?

Again, following the same confusion:
**symbolic execution** is a technique to dynamically analyze an executable file.
One cannot "execute" a firmware image, even less symbolically!

---

What you might want to do is use something like to [firmware-mod-kit](https://github.com/rampageX/firmware-mod-kit) to extract the content of the firmware image you have; Among this content, find the executable you want to test, and then use `angr` to perform all the analyses you want!